# Why is the electric field of an axial quadrupole not the same as the electric field of two axial dipoles, at far distance?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole, multipole-expansion

An axial electric quadrupole, made of four inline charges $(+q, -q, -q, +q)$ with opposite charges a distance $a$ apart, and the two $-q$ charges adjacent, has an electric field at a remote point $P$ a distance $r \gg a$. 
$$E_q = {1 \over 4\pi\epsilon_0}{3Q \over r^4}, 
\qquad \hbox{where } Q = 2a^2q \quad \hbox{(the quadrupole moment)}.$$
This can be found by (vectorially) adding the fields of each individual charge with
$$E = {1 \over 4\pi\epsilon_0}{q \over r^2}.$$
Individual charges distances are $(r-a), r, r, (r+a)$.

Although the axial quadrupole is physically identical to two adjacent axial dipoles, if the quadrupole is treated as two dipoles, and the axial dipole field equation is applied:
$$E_d = {1 \over 2\pi\epsilon_0}{p \over r^3}, 
\qquad \hbox{where }p = 2aq \quad \hbox{(the dipole moment)},$$
the field strength at point $P$ will come out twice as large:
$$E_q = {1 \over 2\pi\epsilon_0}{3Q \over r^4}.$$ 
Dipole distance is not $a$ but $(r-0.5 a)$ and $(r + 0.5 a)$.

Question: Why? Our mathematical analysis should be independent of the physics of the situation, and the answer should be the same.

Comment: You need vectors or else specify the direction from the origin to your point $\vec r$.

Comment: Of course you need vectors, but this is an axial quadrupole, so there are no other components except those on the axis. The origin can just as well be the point $P$.

Comment: If a two-dipole approach and the individual four-charge approach give two different answers to the same physical situation, then it seems that the analytical approach is incorrect--but which one to use?

Comment: "There are no other components except those on the axis" ─ this is false. There's a nonzero off-axis electric field component at all points except on the axis, and your post does not specify whether $P$ lies on or off the axis.

Comment: These 2 are certainly not physically identical.

Comment: The magnitude of the dipole moment of two equal and opposite charges $\pm q$ a distance $a$ apart is $p = qa$, not $p = 2qa$.

Comment: Michael Seifert, That would help a lot if there were a typo in my textbook. It says along the axis p = 2aq. Can you verify this somehow. I don't want to take typos in my textbook lightly.

Comment: Emilio Pisanty: Thank you. The point P lies on the axial line of the both dipoles, at a distance $r+a/2$ and $r-a/2$, for the close and far dipoles respectively. Each dipole has charges a distance $a$ apart.

Comment: Michael Seifert. Thanks for the point in the right direction. I went back and looked at the textbook example carefully and noticed that the book placed the two charges 2a apart, not a; in that case, p = 2aq. By revising it to p=aq to match my problem, the four-charge quadrupole and the two-dipole quadrupole give the same answer.